# LPC1850: why does program execution jump to 0xFFFFFFFE after systick interrupt?

Tags: gcc, interrupt, lpc

I made a working program for LPC1857 which enables interrupts and each systick interrupt then calls some function. It works perfectly with LPC1857. When I try to run the same program on LPC1850 the program execution jumps to 0xFFFFFFFE and stops whenever the interrupt occurs. The function called in the SystickHandler never gets called. It looks like the program gets wrong address for the handler, but I don't understand how that could be. LR points to 0xFFFFFFF9 when that happens. Both of the addresses are reserved.

I changed the linker file (the only difference from LPC1857 project besides the initialization of some unrelated ports) for LPC1850 and it looks like this:

```
ENTRY(_start)                     
INPUT(& &)


MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x1C000000, LENGTH = 16M
    SRAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 64K
}

SECTIONS

    .text :
    {
        _text = .;
        KEEP(*(.isr_vector))
        *startup.o(.text)   
        *(.text*)
        *(.glue_7t) *(.glue_7)
        *(.rodata*)
        _text_end = .;
    } > SRAM

    .bss :
    {
        _bss = .;
        *(.bss*)
        *(COMMON)
        _bss_end = .;
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } > SRAM

    .data : AT (ADDR(.text) + SIZEOF(.text))
    {
        _data = .;
        *(vtable)
        *(.data*)
        _data_end = .;
    } > SRAM

    . = ALIGN(4);
    .ARM.extab : {
      *(.ARM.extab*)
    } > SRAM

    . = ALIGN(4);
    __exidx_start = ABSOLUTE(.);
    .ARM.exidx : {
      *(.ARM.exidx*)
    } > SRAM
    __exidx_end = ABSOLUTE(.);



    .stack :
    {
      _stack_top = . + SIZEOF(.stack);
    } > SRAM
}
```

Do you have any idea what I'm missing? If you need any additional info, let me know.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

While this question is quite ancient, I've ran recently into this kind of problem so here's some answer: in general, when all interrupts lead pc into `0xfffffffe` it indicates that there's something horribly wrong with the vector table. If you're using some HW debugger and you are in this situation, you should check contents of VTOR register[1] in the SCB. It should point to valid vector table (such as section `.isr_vector` generated from GCC ride startup assembly).

LPCxxxx chips are alien to me so I can't give any useful details on those, but for example if LPC1850 and LPC1857 have differences in memory addresses and you set the VTOR somewhere, you might need to set it bit differently. The fact that you're able to boot (invoke reset handler) the LPC1850 in the first place indicates that you have valid vector table where the device is booted from.

[1] `0xe000ed08` http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/Ciheijba.html

Comment: Thanks. It didn't solve my problem, but it's helpful advice.

Answer (score 0):

there's no section in FLASH !? For the 1850 you download your program in external flash with the address 0x1C000000.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work in SRAM? LPC1857 runs perfectly from SRAM.